# Tinymce editor content visible with html tags when i try to display saved content on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, tinymce

1. I have created one functionality in that I'm saving tinyMCE text editor content in a database (along with all html tags),
2. Now when I try to display it on my .cshtml page, it showing content along with html tags

[image: See below images]

below is mycode

[image]

It appears with double quotes in html
[image]
Can someone help me understand why it has such behavior?

Note: I'm working with .net core application with jQuery javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.Raw(Model.Product.Description)` to render raw HTML. Normally, all web engine will "escape" the content for safety.